# Calculate time between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datepicker. i have found the difference between two dates using

```
DateTime  startdate = frmdate_starttime.Date;
DateTime  enddate = frmdate_endtime.Date;
TimeSpan ts1 = enddate.Subtract(startdate);
```

now i want to multiply the timespan value with 10 hrs . but 10 hrs is in datatype int. how can i multiply the timespan value with int val.

Comment: Can you give an example? For instance, 10hrs x 27s = ???

Comment: Do you know that you can mark the useful answers as accepted? Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply a time with a time, you would get a very strange unit like hours squared... I assume that you want to multiply the number of days in the time span by ten hours:

```
int hours = ts1.Days * 24 * 10
```